# no suitable HttpMessageConverter found error while posting using RestTemplate

Tags: spring, rest, spring-boot

I am trying to post and on postman chrome app using URL as shown,

URL = http://example.com/asg/oauth2/access_token?grant_type=client_credentials&scope=public&client_id=abc-xyz-123-456&client_secret=yhlk-pkli-asfd-hgjf

I get a json response:

```
{
"expires_in": 170889,
"token_type": "Bearer",
"access_token": "JKL7ZQnRjPqjFVkEArOVpiJs"
}
```

Now in my Spring boot app ver 1.5, I am making a post as shown below, which throws an error.

```
@Autowired
RestTemplate restTemplate
private ApiAccessToken ApiAccessToken;

ApiAccessToken = restTemplate.postForObject(url, null, ApiAccessToken.class);
```

ApiAccessToken class:

```
public class ApiAccessToken {
    private String expires_in;
    private String token_type;
    private String access_token;
    // ommitted getters & setters
    }
```

pom.xml

```
    `<dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>`
```

Error:

```
org.springframework.web.client.RestClientException: Could not extract response: no suitable HttpMessageConverter found for response type [class com.example.ApiAccessToken] and content type [application/json]
at org.springframework.web.client.HttpMessageConverterExtractor.extractData(HttpMessageConverterExtractor.java:110) ~[spring-web-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.doExecute(RestTemplate.java:655) ~[spring-web-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.execute(RestTemplate.java:613) ~[spring-web-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.postForObject(RestTemplate.java:380) ~[spring-web-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
at com.example.ApiService.setOrUpdateApiAccessToken(ApiService.java:61) ~[classes/:na]
at com.example.Controller.home(Controller.java:16) ~[classes/:na]
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_11]
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_11]
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_11]
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483) ~[na:1.8.0_11]
at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:205) ~[spring-web-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:133) ~[spring-web-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:97) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:827) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:738) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:85) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:967) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:901) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:970) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:861) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:635) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.15.jar:8.5.15]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:846) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:742) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.15.jar:8.5.15]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.15.jar:8.5.15]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.15.jar:8.5.15]
at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52) ~[tomcat-embed-websocket-8.5.15.jar:8.5.15]
```

Comment: You need to have Jackson in your runtime classath.

Comment: I have added spring-boot-starter-web as a dependency in my classpath. Wouldn't this help?

Comment: Yes, it should add jackson as a dependency.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like a configuration problem.
Make sure you have a json serializer installed in your servlet filter chain (servlet-context.xml)

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29076210/convert-a-object-into-json-in-rest-service-by-spring-mvc) can also help